# Listen to multiple HTTPS ports in python

Tags: python, https, tornado

I am trying to read data from multiple ports at once.
But when I try it responds very slow to the data here is my code( works fine with single port). Is there any way to improve the speed

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
   http_server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
   http_server.listen(8082)
   http_server.listen(8080)
   http_server.listen(8200)
   tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

I have tried the below code of adding sockets as well, but it is the same result

```
sockets = tornado.netutil.bind_sockets(8082, '')
server = tornado.httpserver.HTTPServer(application)
server.add_sockets(sockets)

for s in sockets:
  print('Listening on %s, port %d' % s.getsockname()[:2])
tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.instance().start()
```

Comment: Why are you specifically trying to read from multiple ports at once?
Instead of having one instance listening on multiple ports, could you not make the ports configurable and run multiple instances, each listening on a single port?

Comment: Hi @StephanPieterse , Thanks for responding, There is a requirement to read from multiple ports for different data such as command , data , control etc

Comment: I'm not sure if the GIL is affecting you, have you looked at this doc yet
https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/guide/running.html?highlight=multiple%20ports#processes-and-ports
Also, it's still unclear what 'slow' means in this context, the problem could be with the actual application and not with the listener setup.

Comment: Your HTTPS connection should terminate at the reverse proxy. For example, you set up Nginx to listen at port 443 and it will take care of handling SSL. Then Nginx will forward decrypted http requests to your Tornado backend.

Comment: It is seen that there is delay in application side and not the listener set up. Thank you all responses